# why password less ssh not working?

Tags: linux, hadoop, ssh, cluster-computing

I connected 3 data nodes(in all these data nodes pass-wordless is working fine) in my cluster which are working fine but when i try to connect another data node pass-wordless ssh not working in fourth data node.

IP address of first three data nodes:

```
172.20.93.192(name node)
172.20.94.189(data node)
172.20.94.145(data node)
172.20.94.193(data node)
```

now my fourth data node's IP address is 172.20.95.6 where password-less is not working.

I am generating keys with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I am doing the same process for the fourth data node as above three data nodes but it is not working. Why? what may be the reason?

Comment: what is the error when you connect with client cert?

Comment: And also, how do you know it's not working?  What test are you doing?

Comment: You  just need to connect the namenode (93.192) with passwordless ssh to the datanodes. Nothing else.

Comment: Password-less is not working.it is asking me password.I have tested by giving ssh 172.20.95.6(fourth data node IP) in namenode.It is asking password.

Comment: It is not throwing any error but it is asking password,it should not be.

Comment: run `ssh` with option `-v` and look at the output. It will tell you why it asks for a password. And of course make sure that the correct public key is in the *~/.ssh/authorized_keys* file. Or just use `ssh-copy-id` which will do this automagically.

Comment: when i tried with ssh -v it shows the following error : reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for minint-q44435e [172.20.95.6] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!

Comment: I tried ssh-copy-id also but it is not working.

Comment: Looks like the reverse DNS lookup fails. This is a configuration problem of your machine, not an SSH issue. SSH just performs this security check which fails.

Comment: You are going to need proper forward and reverse DNS to work with Hadoop anyway, so you might as well fix this before trying anything else.

Comment: @lakshmi Did you verify, double and triple verify that the correct key is in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on 172.20.95.6 ? ssh is also picky about the permission on both the ~/.ssh/ and the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys , which you should investigate too.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem today with CentOS servers. The problem turned out that the `/root` folder had wrong permissions. In fact, the `/var/log/secure` log file showed this error:

```
Sep  3 09:10:40 nec05 sshd[21858]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root
```

This is what it wrongly was:

```
[root@nec05 ~]# ls -ld /root
drwxrwxrwx. 32 root root 4096 Sep  3 09:54 /root
```

Using `chmod` fixed it:

```
[root@nec05 ~]# chmod 550 /root
[root@nec05 ~]# ls -ld /root
dr-xr-x---. 32 root root 4096 Sep  3 09:54 /root
```

After that, passwordless login worked on this particular server.

Answer (score 1):

More information would be required to get the "real" cause. However here it goes two of the most common problems I have found and not related to the key configuration itself (taking into account that you use Linux :)):

1. SSHD in the remote machine is configured in restricted mode for "root" and you are trying to ssh as root. SOLUTION: Copy /etc/ssh/sshd.conf from one of the working machines to the faulty and restart ssh server.
2. Home folder of the user used for remote login has invalid permissions. Many default configurations for SSH Daemons contain restrictions about the permissions of the user home folder for security purposes. SOLUTION: Compare with working nodes and fix. (Sometimes you would see a warning/error log in /var/log/messages.

If you follow the process to integrate the keys from the scratch and review the permissions for all the files involved you should face no issues.

Please answer back with sshd.conf file as well as the logs from a remote login with -v (ssh -v IPADDR) for a better analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same errors recently.  All my file permissions are set up correctly but still ssh asks for password. Finally I figured out it is due to one missing at /etc/ssh/sshd_config:  you shoud add "AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys", so that sshd will look for the publickey file at your home dir.

After doing this the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to more elaborate your problem i.e. whether you are using the same private-public key pair for all servers.

Secondly you must try ssh with -v flag it will give you some hint like which private key it is using for authentication, what is the cause of authentication failure.

Thirdly Verify the permission of .ssh/authorized_keys at server end. It should not have write permission to group or other users.

You can simply use
ssh-keygen -f  # to generate ssh key pair.
ssh-copy-id @ #to copy public key in the server's authorized key.

Answer (score 0):

troubleshoot checklist:
example: Machine A passwordless login to B

- turn off selinux on B
- FOR BOTH A&B: make sure correct permission for .ssh(700) and .ssh/authorized_keys (600)
- check on B: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: PubkeyAuthentication yes
- check firewall on B
- check the log /var/log/secure
- if you've renamed id_rsa/id_rsa.pub to example id_rsa_b/id_rsa_b.pub, you should do ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa_b user@MachineB

[refer](https://lyhistory.com/docs/software/linux/linux_security.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to explain with example:
Suppose there are two server **server1(192.168.43.21)** and **server2(192.168.43.33)**.If you want password less ssh between server1 and server2 where user is `admin` then follow below steps-

1. To install run command:  `yum install openssh-server openssh-clients`
2. To create ssh key run command : `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on server1 and server2
3. SELINUX disable at : `vim /etc/selinux/conifg`

> SELIINUX=disabled

4. After changing SELINUX need to reboot.
5. Add user to AllowUsers ,AllowGroups and PermitEmptyPasswords on at :

   vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

> AllowUsers admin

> AllowGroups admin

After update restart sshd:  `systemctl restart sshd`

6. Go to home directory of admin user : `cd ~`
7. Go to ssh folder : `cd .ssh`   and copy `id_rsa.pub` key from **server1** and paste it into server **server2**  **authorized.key** file of .ssh folder.

**note:** Instead of manually copy we can use:

```
         From server2 use command: `ssh-copy-id admin@serve1`

         From server1 use command: `ssh-copy-id admin@server2`
```

8. Now try ssh from server1 to server2 and server2 to server1

   ```
        From server1 command: `ssh admin@server2`

        From server2 command: `ssh admin@server1`
   ```
9. If not working then check firewall user use command:
   To check status of firewall run command: `firewall-cmd --state`

   If it is running  then check ssh port is added or not using below command:
   `firewall-cmd --list-all`

   If port is not added then need need to add to desired zone.

   If firewall is not mandatory to active in that cat you can stop firewall and
   mask it using below command:

   `systemctl stop firewalld`

   `systemctl disable firewalld`

   `systemctl mask --now firewalld`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if selinux is disabled.
In my case, worked after selinux disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Method in linux is to generate encrypted key (either with rsa or dsa ) for that user , save that key in authorized key , assign rights to that folder and file in it.

1: Generate key with command

```
ssh-keygen –t dsa –P '' –f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Your public key has been saved in /home/***username_of_pc***/.ssh/id_dsa.pub

2:Add that key in authorized key.

```
Cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Set permissions for folder where it’s saved. 
if you need it on another server then simply copy it to other machine.

3:Check ssh by simply typing

```
    ssh localhost
```

It should not ask for password and only display last login time , then it’s setup correctly. Remember not to use root for ssh.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.